# HTML5 iPad app not working on iPad1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova, settings

I recently developed a phonegap HTML5 app and it is working fine on my iPad 2's and android devices. When I install the app onto my iPad 1's the app installs, the icon disappears, then after rebooting the icon is back and looks as if it is installed.

I can launch the app, and the splash screen is displayed, then the app just closes.

Here are my deployment settings - I'm quite new to this, so if there are any relevant settings you need to know about, let me know and I'll update my post.

[image]

Phonegap version: 3.6.0-0.21.19

iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1

I create project and build via phonegap commandline, but package with xcode then use diawi to distribute to my iPads.

Comment: Knowing the Phonegap and iOS versions will be very useful as different Phonegap version support different iOS versions. Also it would be useful to know if you're installing it to the iPad via the phoengap command line tools or making a .ipa file and installing it OTA.

Comment: @Keab42 I have updated the post with the information

Comment: @bmike I have added these details to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cordova, which Phonegap is based on dropped iOS 5 support with version 3.5.0

You can read the blog post here: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html

So it's likely that the code is reaching some iOS 6 commands and then crashing. I'm afraid, you'll either have to revert to an older version of Phonegap or buy a newer test device.

I would not recommend rolling back to an older version of Phonegap because, from February, Apple will require all apps submitted to include 64-bit support (See here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a), I believe this something that Cordova 3.5.0 introduced.

As for the disappearing/reappearing of the App icon. I used to see that if the bundle identifier given in the .plist file associated with the download was different to the one in the actual app info.plist. I've not used diawi though, so I can't help you beyond that I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Keab, thanks for your answer. As my app is for in-house use only (we send out our ipads with the app pre-installed) and doesn't require submission to the app store, is it still unadvisable to use an older version of phonegap? I'm hesitant to roll back to the older version as I found it quite tricky to set up and get it working.

Comment: Being in-house does overcome some of those issues, but you might run into bugs and other problems that are only resolved in more recent builds. Also if you're using plugins, they tend to be built to work with the latest versions so you might have to find older versions of those too. It's one of those difficult situations I'm afraid. Cordova has a fairly rapid release cycle, though Phonegap themselves are somewhat slower. You'll need to weigh up the pros and cons of both options to decide what's best for your company.

Comment: The app doesn't make use of any 3rd party plugins, and was originally created for the iPad 1 (most of our iPad stock are 1's) - As I use xcode to actually package the apps (create the .ipa), will i also need to downgrade xcode?

Comment: Sounds like you're probably OK to find an older version. I'd recommend 3.4, I think there's a way to use that specific version in the command line tools. As far as I'm aware xCode 6 still supports targets of iOS 5 and 5.1 so you're probably still OK on that front at the moment. Keep an eye on it though, they might remove that from a future update.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems I can still target iOS 4.3 and up with Xcode 6.1. I'll try using phonegap 3.4. The commands to install older versions of phonegap are: 'npm view phonegap versions' and then 'npm install -g phonegap@3.4.0-0.20.4' (for the latest version of 3.4)